# c++ derived class with no variables

Tags: c++

I have a derived class which has no variables but simply adapts the interface to another class - is there a special name for such a class in C++?

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to your question - if you're changing/adapting the interface, derivation might not be appropriate.

Comment: Private inheritance is fine; public isn't.

Answer (score 7):

It "adapts" the interface? Assuming that means that it exposes the same behaviour, but with different method calls (or perhaps, slight behavioural changes), then we tend to call that an **[Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)**. It's a common design pattern.

Related is the [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) pattern, which is an Adapter that simplifies an API. For example, it may provide sensible parameter defaults, or abstract some of the necessary call flow into a unit that can be called by other code.

Comment: Couldn't have said it better myself. :)

Comment: It quite possibly is an adapter, it could still be an adapter even if it had member variables. I don't think either adapter or facade captures both characteristics that the question asks for. But I can't think of a term that does, so I can't really complain.

Answer (score 1):

Rob is correct, what you describe matches the [Adapter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) design pattern.

If it "adapts" more than one class or package behind the scenes, this is also called a [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern).

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything.

Comment: Snarfblam: it looks like Rob added his paragraph about Facade after my post.

Comment: That's right; or rather, as I was editing to add the paragraph about Facade, your post came up. I submitted the edit anyway, no harm done.